# Scene collection dropdown buttons dont work

Tags: python, interface, scene, collections

Nothing happens whenever I try to click on the triangle dropdown icons/buttons in the scene collection menu.

[image: all the dropdown buttons don't work]
I've had this problem for a while now even on older versions of blender, but I can't seem to figure out what is the problem.

Blender version [3.2]
Python version [3.11]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the KeyMapItem `Open/Close` for left mouse in outliner was disabled.

Go to Preferences > Keymap > Outliner > Open/Close with event mouse and type left > tick checkbox left.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much that solved it.